# How do I just include another JS file for modulation purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

So I'm using the stack: MongoDB, NodeJS, Vue/Nuxt, Express, SocketIO and I want to seperate my socket calls into JS files and then combine them all in like an index file and include that in my default.vue layout.

Right now it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- <loader v-if="loading"></loader> -->
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import socket from '~/plugins/socket.io.js'
import Loader from '~/components/init/Loader'
export default {
  components: {
    Loader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true
    }
  },
  created(){
    Promise.all([
      this.$store.dispatch('todos/INIT'),
    ]).then(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.loading = false
      }, 1000);
    });  

    socket.on('new-item', (data) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('todos/ADD', data.item)
    })
    socket.on('check-item', (data) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('todos/CHECK', data.item)
    })
    socket.on('removed-item', (data) => {
      this.$store.dispatch('todos/REMOVE', data.item)
    })

  }
}
</script>
<style>
  html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}
</style>
```

I want to be able to just include a file that contains all my socket.on functions so theres not 800 lines of socket.on's but I can't seem to figure out the best way. module.exports hasn't seemed to work for me neither has just requiring the file.

Comment: Looks like you just need a map to go from `new-item` to `todos/ADD`, etc.  Then, you could loop through that map to set up the appropriate handlers.

Comment: @Brad im unsure what you mean, could you give me an example? The goal for me would be to just include it in a plugin or the main file and have all of the socket.ons in organized files that are all eventually called to one place. As a large scale application could have thousands of socket.ons

Comment: Either I'm not fully understanding your question, or you're confused on what needs to happen.  :-)  As far as I can tell, the root problem has absolutely nothing to do with including a file.  The issue is that you want a clean way to map events from Socket.IO to dispatch calls on `$store`.  Where and how you include it doesn't matter.  Is that accurate?  if not, can you clarify?

Comment: @Brad sorry, what I am aiming to achieve is to instead putting every socket.on on the main page I would be able to split it up into different js files to make it more neat an organized as my application scales. Rather that continuing to add a new socket.on function for every component that uses sockets

Comment: It sounds like what you actually need is a better abstraction between what you're sending/receiving via Socket.IO, and what's happening in the app client-side.  If your naming were consistent, for example, you could have a generic event handler that then dispatched things generically.  If instead of an event named `new-item`, it were named `todos/ADD`, then you would need only one of these event handlers for the whole app.

Comment: @Brad honestly im still learning as I go, im not really sure what you mean. Im currently building a base templating that I can use for any project I device to build with this stack